# How to write a function which takes n number of arguments and gets called n number of times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was asked the below question where one function takes n number of arguments and gets called n times. I could not get answers anywhere. Please help me with below code

```
test(1, 2, 3, 4,5 ....n)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....n)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....n)........
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the only detail, you were given? You can use rest operator to get dynamic parameters, It could be any number and its has the results in the form of array. SO you can read the length property to run the loop.

If you can provide more details, the solution can be improved.

```js
const a = (...arg) => {
  console.log(arg);
  if (arg.length === 0) return `No Args`;

  arg.forEach((el, index, arr) => {
      // do things here 
  }) 
}

a(1, 2, 4, 5)
console.log(a())
```

Or what I can see from the question you can use cascaded(closure )function like this:

```js
const mul = a => b => c => a*b*c;

console.log(mul(1)(2)(3));
```

You can also return the function body itself and call it n times.

```js
const funcCall = (...params) => {
    console.log(params);
return funcCall
}  

funcCall(1, 2, 3)(4, 5, 6)(7, 8, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is rest syntax. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) Following is an example of rest syntax -

```
function test(...args) {
  console.log(args);//array
  for (let element of args) {
  //do something
  }
}
test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```